# Unexpected result using _.result(obj, 'path') in lodash node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

Using lodash inside a node.js module – at the beggining with `var _ = require('lodash')` –  I noticed that the access behaviour of `_.result()` using a string as the path `"a.b.c"` (using more than one level), simply returns undefined...

So I felt forced to test (inside node.js):

```
var obj = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c1': 3, 'c2': _.constant(4) } }] }
                            , test1 = _.result(obj, 'a')
                            , test2 = _.result(obj, 'a[0].b.c2');
test1 = _.result(test1, '0')
test1 = _.result(test1, 'b')
test1 = _.result(test1, 'c2')

console.log('| 1:', test1, '| 2:', test2);
```

Results: `| 1: 4 | 2: undefined`

In webstorm, I evaluate the docs' expression `_.result({ 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c1': 3, 'c2': _.constant(4) } }] }, 'a[0].b.c2')` and it should be 4, not undefined, right?
Ref: https://lodash.com/docs#result

In order to be sure I did the same here in this plunk 
`http://plnkr.co/edit/TcbH7zhyCPNdKIA34Va8`

Has someone ever faced it before? Is it a known bug? Or, shame on me, and just there's an unnoticed detail here?!

Thanks!

Comment: I copied and pasted your code above into a file, added `var _ = require('lodash');` above it, and it returned `4` for both values instead of `undefined` for the second value. I tried lodash 3.9.3 and 3.8.0 and it didn't seem to matter.

Comment: You must be using an older version, as that would be the expected output _before_ [deep path support](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#v370) was introduced.